# By default, where is the membership data saved in Asp.Net MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I create MVC application, run it and register.
I cannot find the location the membership data saved.
Where is it?

Note: The application run on developer web server (cassini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default MVC application will store user credentials in aspnetdb.mdf which will reside in your App_Data directory. When you run the application the file will be created and attached to SQL Server Express if it doesn't already exist.

Open your web.config file and check out the "ApplicationServices" connection string to see the default values.